# What does the animation duration in frames mean?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations, vivus

I have been using vivus.js for tiny svg animations for a while now , now this plugin has the following initialization format:

```
new Vivus('my-div', {duration: 200, file: 'link/to/my.svg'}, myCallback);
```

dead simple to use , now my question is about the `duration: 200` parameter. see the documentation for it **[HERE](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus#option-list)**. Now whenever i use jquery and other librarys etc `1000` means 1 secound , but here what is `200` is not very clear , the documentation says the followning:

**duration**  ::    Animation duration, in frames. [Default: 200].

Now what exactly is animation duration in frames supposed to mean ? what is `200` really here 2000 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood vivus is using `requestAnimationFrame` so it deals in frames instead of milliseconds.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus/issues/72

From the above link `You can keep in mind an average score of 30 frames per second and adapt your instance with it.`

The code located at the mozilla link does work, it just doesn't show anything visual (at least in jfiddle).

Here's a working example that shows movement.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ej3Legg/

HTML

```
<div id="anim">
  <span id="blah">asdasf</span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var start = null;
var element = document.getElementById("blah");

function step(timestamp) {
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  var progress = timestamp - start;
  element.style.position = "absolute";
  element.style.left = Math.min(progress / 10, 500) + "px";
  if (progress < 100000) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Comment: so it will not adapt to the screens refresh-rate, but slow it down to 30 whenever possible?!

Comment: @Jazzepi http://jsfiddle.net/gg0h2n0u/ the code provided at MSN does absolutly nothing !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik It does actually update the left position value. I included a link to a modified version of your fiddle to show it animating some text.

Comment: @CodeiSir I'm not an expert in this area, but I think the underlying idea is that you tell the OS your target framerate and it does it's best to match that. It also prevents you from doing a bunch of extraneous draws. There's a decent bit of information here. http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Animation%20and%20Ticker/ Scroll down to the "Timiing Modes" section. This is for EasleJS but it has an option to use requestAnimationFrame under the hood.

Comment: @Jazzepi so in the fiddle example that you provided , suppose i say : `element.style.left = '500px';` then before the element reachs 500px to the left, the function `window.requestAnimationFrame(step);` is called .. is that right ?

Answer (score 1):

What you mean by "whenever i use jQuery and other librarys etc 1000 means 1" are milliseconds, wich are part of seconds.

Frames are a different concept. It's a discrete time management (steps). You will have a certain amount of *frames per second* "fps".

You be able to set the speed of the frames with:

`play(speed)`  Plays the animation with the speed given in parameter. This value can be negative to go backward, between 0 and 1 to go slowly, or superior to 1 to go fast. [Default:  1 ]

I can't find anywhere on the Internet how many frames per second a speed of 1 will be, but you can just test it. <s>Might be 100.</s> About 30 Frames per second (from Jazzepi's answer)